# PHP pass by reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I have the following code. I am expecting the check method `hasQuerystring()` to pass the modified `url` ..

However, the result shows that the hasQuerystring always returns false, meaning, the parameter is not pointing to the modified `url`..

Here is the code:

```
private function __addParams(&$url, $params, $addedParams = null) {
    if(!empty($addedParams)) {
        foreach($params as $param => $val) {
            if(!in_array($param, $addedParams)) {
                $url .= ($this->__hasQuerystring($url))? "&{$param}={$val}" : "?{$param}={$val}" ;
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach($params as $param => $val) {
            $url .= ($this->__hasQuerystring($url))? "&{$param}={$val}" : "?{$param}={$val}" ;
        }
    }
    return $url;
}   

private function __hasQuerystring($url) {
    return strpos('?',$url);
}
```

**[EDIT]**

This is the value of `url` before being returned

`https://mobile.domain.com/en/#/#m=2&eid=123?param1=9675?param2=23d9dj8rsaE3dG1`

Comment: Check Erik answer. I've also edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `strpos` you pass the thing to search in first, then the thing to search for next.
See the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
return strpos($url, '?') !== FALSE;
```

Comment: I forgot that in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return strpos('?',$url);
```

with

```
return strpos($url, '?') !== FALSE;
```

Always check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

That's why is always returning FALSE.

Also, if you don't use the result from `__addParams`, you can remove `return $url;`

**Later edit:**

I replaced  `return strpos('?',$url) !== FALSE;` with `return strpos($url, '?') !== FALSE;` as Erik pointed.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. However, this did not solve my problem.. Oh and yes I am using the returned url value..

Comment: Then `print_r($url);` before `return $url;`

Comment: `That's why is always returning FALSE.` this is kinda ambiguous. Why is it always returning false?

Comment: Ofcourse.. Wrong parameter order passing.. Thanks for that. @Glavić.. so that is why it returns false. thank you both.. I really thought it was a pass by reference prob rather than this silly mistake..